# Taj Mahal Ticket Booking

Tags: india, history, agra

Although for Taj Mahal, the entry is free for kids below 15 years, you are supposed to add the details of your child while booking the entry tickets on https://asi.payumoney.com In my case it allows me to add adults but it doesn't allow me to add the details of the child, the button "Add Child" is not activated (its in grey). I have tried with different browsers but still the problem persists. Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not you - it does the same for me too :)

Comment: `https://asi.payumoney.com` wow that is some website.

Comment: Since children do not need a ticket, their details need not be entered. Even if you trick the website into adding children (edit the HTML using Inspect tab), the next step will fail with error "Cannot book ticket for child for Taj Mahal".

Answer (score 3):

> Since children do not need a ticket, their details need not be
> entered. Even if you trick the website into adding children (edit the
> HTML using Inspect tab), the next step will fail with error "Cannot
> book ticket for child for Taj Mahal"

From comment

Answer (score -2):

Copy the following snippet:

```
const addChildBtn = document.querySelector('body > asi-root > div.bg.row > div > div > asi-quick-pay-all > div > div > div.col-sm-12.col-md-4.col-lg-4.borderRight > div > div > form:nth-child(1) > div.col-sm-6.col-md-6.col-lg-6.col-xs-6.leftDiv.manualInput > div > button')
addChildBtn.removeAttribute('disabled')
```

- Go the the page where `Add child` button is present.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>
- Paste What you copied (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

And the `Add child` button should be enabled now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community the answer is perfectly fine and includes all steps needed to get the desired results. since this is not a code-based forum, i'm not explaining the (although simple) lines of code. please point out what exactly you saw incorrectly instead of going with the default comments SE has provided you.